# How can I solve the problem occur in osmnx plot_graph_route() KeyError: 'length'

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I am currently developing an optimal delivery algorithm for parcel delivery. I have a question because I encountered a problem with the plot_graph_route() function of OSMNX while developing the program.
When I coded like the code below, I get a result of KeyError: 'length'.

Here is the error code.

```
"C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\osmnx\plot.py", line 303, in plot_graph_route
    data = min(G.get_edge_data(u, v).values(), key=lambda d: d["length"])
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\osmnx\plot.py", line 303, in <lambda>
    data = min(G.get_edge_data(u, v).values(), key=lambda d: d["length"])
KeyError: 'length'
```

As a result of my testing, it is assumed that an error occurs between the two nodes in List A below. Both nodes are connected, and an error occurs even though I arbitrarily added an edge between the two nodes. The path between the nodes is the result obtained by using the netwokX's shortest_path_length() function.

this is my code

```
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
import requests
import numpy as np

a= [1916534315,1916534308] #list_of_problem_node
G = ox.graph_from_place('Gumi, Gyeongsangbuk-do, Korea', network_type='drive')#graph of I want to find 

########## for save and load convinience
# ox.save_graphml(G,'gumimap')
# G = ox.load_graphml('gumimap')

G.add_edge(1916534315,1916534308)
G.add_edge(1916534308,1916534315)
G=ox.utils_graph.get_largest_component(G,strongly=True)

path=nx.shortest_path_length(G,a[0],a[1])
fig1_1, ax = ox.plot_graph_route(G, path, route_linewidth=6, node_size=0.5)
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error suggests, your new edges lack a `length` attribute, which the `plot_graph_route` function needs. You can add it manually or use the `add_edge_lengths` function. https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.add_edge_lengths